# How to use alert with ajax form submit

Tags: javascript, ajax, bootstrap-modal, dom-events, ajaxform

I use ajax to submit form I use this code to confirm the submit and display the message in same page within html:

```
 $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "process.php",
            data: {input1:class1b,input2:class2b},
            dataType: "JSON",
            success:  
            function(data) {
             $("#message").html(data);
             $("#message").addClass(" alert-info ");
            },
            error: function(err) {
            $("#message").html(err);
           $("#message").addClass(" alert-danger");

            }
        });
```

And I use this code for alert message instead of display in html.

```
  $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "process.php",
            data: {input1:class1b,input2:class2b},
            dataType: "JSON",
            success:  
            function(data) {
            alert(data);
            },
            error: function(err) {
            alert(err);
          
            }
        });
```

Both code work fine, however I need to use another alert type using this code:

```
$("#message").modal({backdrop: "static"});
```

First I add this code in top:

```
 <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Alert</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Message.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
```

But I do not know where to add this code inside ajax code, or how to use it to display alert message received.

```
$("#message").modal({backdrop: "static"});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can place the HTML for the bootstrap modal anywhere in the code. After that replace the alert with `$("#message").modal('show');`